# Lubridate problems with NA

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

Why am I getting `NA` when parsing this date?

```
 library(lubridate)
 d2 <- "2015-Mar-07"
 ymd(d2)

 > NA
```

I'm not getting failures with some other examples. Is it because `Mar` is in Spanish? How can I force it to parse the date?

My locale settings:

```
> readr::locale()
<locale>
Numbers:  123,456.78
Formats:  %AD / %AT
Timezone: UTC
Encoding: UTF-8
<date_names>
Days:   Sunday (Sun), Monday (Mon), Tuesday (Tue), Wednesday (Wed), 
Thursday (Thu), Friday (Fri), Saturday (Sat)
Months: January (Jan), February (Feb), March (Mar), April (Apr), May 
(May), June (Jun), July (Jul), August (Aug),
    September (Sep), October (Oct), November (Nov), December (Dec)
AM/PM:  AM/PM
```

Thanks

Comment: `Mar` should work in Spanish or English, though other months could cause problems. What are you locale settings? `readr::locale()` gives a nice summary.

Comment: Added locale settings to the post

Comment: Sorry - I can't reproduce. `lubridate::ymd("2015-Mar-07")` works fine for me with lubridate 1.7.4 and R 3.6.3. Maybe restart R and verify? Or  maybe you have other packages loaded with `ymd` functions masking `lubridate`'s version? Try specifying `lubridate::ymd`.

Comment: It may be what you say, because `mdy`,`dmy`, etc. works fine, I'm only getting the problem with `ydm`. Thanks anyway for your help!!

Comment: If that is the problem, then  using `lubridate::ydm` should solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Everything works fine here. Could you check the **lubridate** version you have installed? I have v1.7.4 on R 3.6.3.

```
library(lubridate)
d2 <- "2015-Mar-07"
> ymd(d2)
[1] "2015-03-07"
```

Alternatively, you can use base R and force the format:

```
d2 <- "2015-Mar-07"
d2new = as.Date(d2, format = "%Y-%b-%d")
> d2new
[1] "2015-03-07"
```

Comment: How about R version? `lubridate` relies on base R `strptime` for alphabetic months - per `?ymd`

Comment: R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)

Comment: How can I force it? @contefranz

Comment: @AlbertoTorrejonValenzuela I would just try with base R: `d2 <- "2015-Mar-07"` and then `as.Date(d2, format = "%Y-%b-%d")`. If it works, I will update the answer above.

Comment: I do get it parsed forcing it. What a weird thing. Thanks!